# How to give Touchable Opacity for each item in grid view in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, gridview, jsx

I am using `react-native-super-grid` for grid view in React Native. I want to give touchable opacity for each item. How do I do that. I want to navigate to corresponding page on each click of grid item. Following is my code.

```
render(){
    return(

      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <SuperGridSectionList
  itemDimension={130}
  sections={[
    {
      title: 'Home Page',
      data: [
        { name: 'New Work Request', code: '#8e44ad' }, { name: 'Worker', code: '#2c3e50' },
        { name: 'Report', code: '#f1c40f' }, { name: 'Complaints', code: '#e67e22' },
        { name: 'User', code: '#e74c3c' }
      ]
    },
  ]}
  style={styles.gridView}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={console.log("clicked")}>
    <View style={[styles.itemContainer, { backgroundColor: item.code }]}>
      <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
  renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
    <Text style={{ color: 'green' }}>{section.title}</Text>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the question is. Is the `TouchableOpactiy` not working (i.e. the `console.log` isn't appearing)? Do you need to know how to get the navigation to work? Something else? What are you seeing vs. what do you expect/want to see?

Comment: When I click on an item in grid view I want to navigate to the corresponding page.Say for ex:if I click on `New Work Request` I want to navigate to the page listing that request , and for `worker` I want to navigate to another page listing workers. So I want to write navigation within `TouchableOpacity`. I'm using `react-native-router-flux`. So `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.workRequest} >`. Like this how do I achieve navigation on each grid item?

Comment: What does `item` look like? Does it have a property that you can use in a switch block? I _think_ what you're looking for is to create a function that returns the correct Action and takes the item discriminator as the parameter, and you would pass that function to `onPress`.

Comment: If I give `id` to each item within `data`array as an unique identifier of `grid item`. How do I pass this to `Actions.firstPage(id:id)` , and for the next one `Actions.secondPage(id:id)`. I don't know whether I'm correct or not.Please help me.Is it possible for navigation to different screens for item within grid?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `item` has a `type` or similar property to distinguish where to navigate to, something like this should get you at least partway there:

```
const getNavigation = (item) => {
  switch (item.type) {
    case 'firstPage':
      return Actions.firstPage(item.id);
    case 'secondPage':
      return Actions.secondPage(item.id);
  }
}

render() {
  // ...
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.getNavigation(item)}>
  // ...
}
```